# Ninject with MVC4 - Binding all assemblies in bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

I am following this article to create a [pluggable MVC application](http://www.squarewidget.com/pluggable-architecture-in-asp.net-mvc-4). Once `ninject` has been installed, it says to add this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"); 
kernel.Bind(a => a.FromAssembliesInPath(path).SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface());
```

to the `RegisterServices` method in the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file, however, when I do this, I get the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Type[]' because it is
>   not a delegate type.

This is fair enough, I understand the error but I'm not sure how to get around it. Has something changed in ninject to cause this error? I would appreciate some advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Bind` method with the signature `Bind(this IBindingRoot kernel, Action<IFromSyntax> configure)` - which was used in the article - is declared as an **extension method** in the `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` namespace's `ExtensionsForIKernel` class inside the ninject.extensions.convention plugin.

So you are missing the right `using` statement.

Add this line to the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file to make your code compile:

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
```